# Running Raw sql query in django signal giving is throwing error

Tags: sql, django, common-table-expression

I am trying to run a CTE in my django application

I have a model

```
class WorkflowStepDependency(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    step = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowStep', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='step')
    step_dependency = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowStep', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='step_dependency')
    step_dependency_status = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowStepStatus', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.step}'s dependency on {self.step_dependency}'s {self.step_dependency_status}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']
```

I am trying to run a cte in one of my signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=WorkflowStepInstance)
def workflowStepInstanceUpdated(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    table_names = connection.introspection.table_names()
    print(table_names)

    if not created:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:

            cursor.execute("""
                   WITH hierarchy
                   AS (
                       SELECT step
                           ,step_dependency
                           ,1 AS lvl
                       FROM Projects_workflowstepdependency
                       WHERE step = %s

                       )
                       ,lvls
                   AS (
                       SELECT lvl
                           ,step
                       FROM hierarchy
                       GROUP BY lvl
                           ,step
                       )
                   """,
                           [instance.workflow_step]
                           )
```

This is giving me error saying

[image]

Comment: Which type and value has `instance.workflow_step`?

Comment: It appears there is no `SELECT` statement after your second CTE `lvls`. Are you missing part of your query or are you expecting the results of `lvls` be returned?